# Why is my database 5 times larger in size than all the individual files combined?

Tags: postgresql

I have 1000 csv files that have a total size of 200 MB.

When I import these files into a new database table, the final size is 1 GB.

Why is this happening, and how do I reduce the size of my database?

I’ve tried using data type constraints to the columns such as using integers instead of varchar where possible, but it doesn’t seem to reduce the size to anywhere near 200 MB.

I’m using Postgres 10.

Comment: Well a database is a "little" more than just a bunch of CSV files...

Comment: In a word - **"overhead"**! Try creating a completely "empty" schema - do a `du -h` on your data directory before and after... Not to mention all of the other factors mentioned by @matigo. Create a new Firebird database (interesting single file architecture there) and you'll have a 1GB file without one byte of user data being entered! How do you think that RDBMS servers enforce referential integrity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the database will depend greatly on a number of factors, including:

- Column data types
- Column collations
- Indexes
- Transaction logs
- Undo logs
- Stored procedures
- Functions
- and on and on and on

If the goal is to have the smallest possible footprint on the storage device, then all of these things need to be considered. If the goal is to have a decently-indexed, performant database, then sometimes a little extra storage consumption is necessary. Many of the database backups at my employer are about 110GB uncompressed, but consume close to three times this when loaded into the database.

Comment: Data types, collations, functions and procedure will hardly use any storage space. There are no undo logs. But yes, there is a lot of overhead, mostly indexes.